# Error Creating custom taglib in Liferay 7.4 using react

Tags: reactjs, liferay, react-component, taglib, liferay-7

I am trying to create a custom taglib in Liferay-DXP-7.4-u31. I have added the react component (referred to from the Liferay source). I am getting below error in the browser console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at ?browserId=chrome&minifierType=&languageId=en_GB&t=1660990296310&/o/js/resolved-module/portal-template-react-renderer-impl@5.0.6/render.es.js&/o/js/resolved-module/*****.taglib@1.0.0/AssetCategoriesSelectorTag.es.js&/o/js/resolved-module/frontend-js-web@5.0.44/bridge/frontend-js-web/liferay/delegate/delegate.es.js&/o/js/resolved-module/frontend-js-web@5.0.44/bridge/frontend-js-web/liferay/toast/commands/OpenToast.es.js:17:1)



 liferay-amd-loader | 
 A require() call has failed but no failure handler was provided.
 Note that even if the call stack of this error trace looks like coming from the Liferay AMD Loader, it is not an error in the Loader what has caused it, but an error caused by the require() call.
 The reason why the Loader is in the stack trace is because it is printing the error so that it doesn't get lost.
 However, we recommend providing a failure handler in all require() calls to be able to recover from errors better and to avoid the appearance of this message.
 
 Some information about the require() call follows:
   · Require call id: 2 
   · Required modules: (4) ['portal-template-react-renderer-impl@5.0.6/render.es', '****.taglib@1.0.0/AssetCategoriesSelectorTag.es', 'frontend-js-web/liferay/delegate/delegate.es', 'frontend-js-web/liferay/toast/commands/OpenToast.es'] 
   · Missing modules: (4) ['portal-template-react-renderer-impl@5.0.6/render.es', '****.taglib@1.0.0/AssetCategoriesSelectorTag.es', 'frontend-js-web@5.0.44/bridge/frontend-js-web/liferay/delegate/delegate.es', 'frontend-js-web@5.0.44/bridge/frontend-js-web/liferay/toast/commands/OpenToast.es']0: "portal-template-react-renderer-impl@5.0.6/render.es"1: "****.taglib@1.0.0/AssetCategoriesSelectorTag.es"2: "frontend-js-web@5.0.44/bridge/frontend-js-web/liferay/delegate/delegate.es"3: "frontend-js-web@5.0.44/bridge/frontend-js-web/liferay/toast/commands/OpenToast.es"length: 4[[Prototype]]: Array(0) 
   · Stack trace of the require() call: 
        Error
            at e.value (http://localhost:8080/o/frontend-js-loader-modules-extender/loader.js?&mac=8TOodH/f/0adFbM2161Kv7ZtPbo=&browserId=chrome&languageId=en_GB&minifierType=js:2:16972)
            at http://localhost:8080/c/portal/layout?p_l_id=355&****_search_web_portlet_SearchPortlet_mvcRenderCommandName=%2Fcall-transfer&p_p_id=****_search_web_portlet_SearchPortlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=pop_up&****_search_web_portlet_SearchPortlet_bodyCssClass=dialog-iframe-popup+search-dialog-iframe-popup:2589:16 
 Error: Load timeout for modules: portal-template-react-renderer-impl@5.0.6/render.es,****.taglib@1.0.0/AssetCategoriesSelectorTag.es,frontend-js-web/liferay/delegate/delegate.es,frontend-js-web/liferay/toast/commands/OpenToast.es
    at loader.js?&mac=8TOodH/f/0adFbM2161Kv7ZtPbo=&browserId=chrome&languageId=en_GB&minifierType=js:2:20444
value @ loader.js?&mac=8TOodH/f/0adFbM2161Kv7ZtPbo=&browserId=chrome&languageId=en_GB&minifierType=js:2
n @ loader.js?&mac=8TOodH/f/0adFbM2161Kv7ZtPbo=&browserId=chrome&languageId=en_GB&minifierType=js:2
(anonymous) @ loader.js?&mac=8TOodH/f/0adFbM2161Kv7ZtPbo=&browserId=chrome&languageId=en_GB&minifierType=js:2
(anonymous) @ loader.js?&mac=8TOodH/f/0adFbM2161Kv7ZtPbo=&browserId=chrome&languageId=en_GB&minifierType=js:2
(anonymous) @ loader.js?&mac=8TOodH/f/0adFbM2161Kv7ZtPbo=&browserId=chrome&languageId=en_GB&minifierType=js:2
setTimeout (async)
value @ loader.js?&mac=8TOodH/f/0adFbM2161Kv7ZtPbo=&browserId=chrome&languageId=en_GB&minifierType=js:2
(anonymous) @ loader.js?&mac=8TOodH/f/0adFbM2161Kv7ZtPbo=&browserId=chrome&languageId=en_GB&minifierType=js:2
Promise.then (async)
value @ loader.js?&mac=8TOodH/f/0adFbM2161Kv7ZtPbo=&browserId=chrome&languageId=en_GB&minifierType=js:2
(anonymous) @ layout?p_l_id=355&****_search_web_portlet_SearchPortlet_mvcRenderCommandName=%2Fcall-transfer&p_p_id=****_search_web_portlet_SearchPortlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=pop_up&****_search_web_portlet_SearchPortlet_bodyCssClass=dialog-iframe-popup+search-dialog-iframe-popup:2589
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Just an error message does not make a good question (see [ask])

Comment: @Prashant Ballal did you find any solution?